# Need help working with Abstract Classes and Generics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

i'm trying to build a class library for all of my mvc-5 projects. For that task i started with setting up some Abstract Classes for my DB Context and Indentity User like this

```
Public MustInherit Class ApplicationUserAbstract
    Inherits IdentityUser

End Class

Public MustInherit Class DatabaseContextAbstract
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Users as DBSet(of ApplicationUserAbstract)


    Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(nameOrConnectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(nameOrConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)


    End Sub
End Class
```

I think i have to get another approach to set DatabaseContextAbstract.Users to the correct Class inherting something like T of ApplicationUserAbstract. Any sugestions for that? I have no clue how to pass this to Users except Using something like

```
Public MustInherit Class DatabaseContextAbstract(of T as ApplicationUserAbstract)
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Users as DBSet(of T)

End Class
```

My next question: how would i access the current Instance of DatabaseContextAbstract in my abstract class? All approaches of DatabaseContextAbstract(of DatabaseContextAbstract(... would be nonsense...

EDIT:

The basic idea behind this is to pack Tables and Functions in that abstract Classes. e.g. There are the same UserRight and Group Tables behind every ApplicationUser in all of my projects. But every project may have project specific tables additionally to the base tables. There is still just one Application user in every project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a whole lot of point to what you're doing here. `IdentityUser` is already abstract. It's intended that you're going to create a concrete class that inherits from it. If you perhaps intended to have multiple different types of users that all shared some subset of custom properties, I could see maybe adding an abstract subclass of `IdentityUser` that implements those, but you're not doing that here. However, even if you did, the user for Identity is a bit of a special case. You can only have one user table, so inheritance must start from a concrete base class, regardless. For example, the following will work fine:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}
public class FooUser : ApplicationUser {}
public class BarUser : ApplicationUser
```

This will *not* work:

```
public abstract class ApplicationUserAbstract : IdentityUser {}
public class FooUser : ApplicationUserAbstract {}
public class BarUser : ApplicationUserAbstract {}
```

In the second scenario, `FooUser` and `BarUser` would get separate tables, which is not supported by Identity. In the first scenario, single-table inheritance will be utilized so `FooUser` and `BarUser` will be in the same table as `ApplicationUser`, with a discriminator column.

When it comes to your context, again, there's limited utility in having a base abstract context class. The context is inherently tied to a database, and it doesn't make sense to have multiple context each interacting with its own unique database that are all virtually carbon-copies. Even if you're dealing with a multi-tenant app, you only need one context. The individualization of the databases would be handled via the connection string, not which context class is utilized.

Finally, if you're using Identity, your context should inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, not `DbContext`. Among other things `IdentityDbContext` already contains a `DbSet` for users, so the one you added is unnecessary.

Long and short, none of this code does anything for an application. It's pointless abstraction for the sake of abstraction.

Comment: I'm having some DatabaseTables and Functions, which are implemented in every project. My idea behind AppicationUserAbstract is to put all this stuff in my class library and then just inheriting those Tables and Functions by creating ConcreteApplicationUser Inherits ApplicationUserAbstract.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I create an implementation as the first scenarion in my MVC5 application where ASP.NET Identity is used. The problem is that; I create a user by passing the ApplicationUser model to the UserManager.Create() method and the Discriminator in the database is ApplicationUser instead of FooUser or BarUser. So, how to create FooUser or BarUser? Could you please add an update? >>>

Comment: @ChrisPratt For example I have a register form for both type of user and I let the user to select type on the register form (Foo or Bar). Then should I pass the ModelView containing both of these models to the Controller? If so, which model should I pass to the UserManager.Create() method? I am confused with this and would be appreciated if you post an example. Thanks a lot...

Comment: `UserManager` is an instance of `UserManager<TUser>`, where the generic type parameter `TUser` is being supplied as `ApplicationUser`. As a result, whatever you do with the default `UserManager` instance, will be as `ApplicationUser`. If you need to work with a different user type, `FooUser` for example, then you need an instance of `UserManager<FooUser>`.

Comment: Essentially, right now, every `FooUser`, etc. you're passing into things like `UserManager.Create` is being downcasted to `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations... Voted+